# Is it possible to add static styles.css include via HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Basically I would like to have line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./customStyles.css">
```

that will be last one in style assets.

`customStyles.css` is generated dynamically on server (not via webpack)

so I just want to paste this line of html there and be sure that **it goes after all automatically generated includes**.

when I just place it in head I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./customStyles.css">
<link href="styles/fonts.2d7979e72c5898d0367804a3b6e900d1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="styles/styles.52389c21860a21759b3a2157c3e5730f.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin`?